# Downgrade inline conditional from .net6 to .netframework 4.6.1

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0

I have project written with **.net6 core** I'm trying to downgrade code to **.NETframework 4.6.1** facing some issues with it, particularly conditional inline statement.

as I know in.NETframework conditional if usage like this

```
 var DecodedPayload = valid ? true : false
```

but in .net6 written like this with some additional part after statementز

```
 var DecodedPayload = valid ? true : false, IsValid = valid
```

**UPDATED**

I think some important hints was missing in my question, maybe usefull to explain, this workinig code from .net6 I forgot to point that conditionl statment evaluated inside the return scope, see the original code .

```
   private VerifiedDecodedDataModel<TNotificationData> GetVerifiedDecodedData<TNotificationData>(string signedPayload)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(signedPayload))
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Signed Payload is null");
            }

            var splitParts = signedPayload.Split('.'); // JWS header, payload, and signature representations

            EnsurePartElements(splitParts);

            var valid = VerifyToken(signedPayload);
            
            var payload = splitParts[1];

            return new VerifiedDecodedDataModel<TNotificationData> 
            {
                DecodedPayload = valid ? DecodeFromBase64<TNotificationData>(payload) : default,
                IsValid = valid
            };
        }
```

what the purpose of this addition after comma?

Thanks

Comment: to be explicit: `var DecodedPayload = valid ? true : false, IsValid = valid;` is not valid in any compiler version (to date), and should yield `CS0819` "Implicitly-typed variables cannot have multiple declarators"

Comment: Would you try this first : change you csproj to have the target framework you want (eg : net461) but make sure to specify `<LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>`. Should allow to use the newest language features with an old framework. (default c# language level for .NET Framework is 7.3 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version)

Comment: I'm very sorry I miss that was a function and the second part is a parameter pass to function, so the error actual in the function it self not in the conditional statement part. ;(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the update:

```cs
return new VerifiedDecodedDataModel<TNotificationData> 
{
    DecodedPayload = valid ? DecodeFromBase64<TNotificationData>(payload) : default,
    IsValid = valid
};
```

this is *object initializer* syntax; the comma simply marks the end of each member assignment (there can optionally be a final redundant comma after the last assignment). Like `var`, this again is valid in C# 3 or above, which is the same timeframe as .NET Framework 3.5, so: it should not present any difficulty, however: it is *equivalent* to:

```cs
var tmp = new VerifiedDecodedDataModel<TNotificationData>();
tmp.DecodedPayload = valid ? DecodeFromBase64<TNotificationData>(payload) : default;
tmp.IsValid = valid;
return tmp;
```

Again, you should not need to change anything here. If it isn't working / compiling, you should post the exact message that you're seeing.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure it didn't say `bool DecodedPayload = valid ? true : false, IsValid = valid;` ? in which case: it defines two booleans, calculates the first via the conditional, then assignes the second from `valid`. Akin to two statements:

```cs
bool DecodedPayload = valid ? true : false;
bool IsValid = valid;
```

(note that the two lines are functionally identical, though!)

Note that `var` can only declare and assign *one* local, where-as explicit types can declare (and optionally assign) as many as you like *of that same type* - comma separated.

Note also: any such change is not related to the framework version, but rather: the language/compiler version, and: `var` goes back *almost all the way* (it was added in C# 3 at the same time as .NET Framework 3.5), so... I doubt you need to change *anything* here.

Comment: Please see updated part of my question may be help to explain.

Comment: I'm very sorry I miss that was a function and the second part is a parameter pass to function, so the error actual in the function it self not in the conditional statement part. ;

Comment: @MohammedIsmael no, it isn't (a parameter pass to function); please see my second post...